# How to replace previous URL parameters using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I had this function to get and replace my `URL` parameter:

```
function getURLParameters(paramName) {
    var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var arrParams = sURL.split("?");
        var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");
        var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);

        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arrURLParams.length; i++) {
            var sParam = arrURLParams[i].split("=");
            arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
            if (sParam[1] !== "")
                arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
            else
                arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < arrURLParams.length; i++) {
            if (arrParamNames[i] === paramName) {
                return arrParamValues[i];
            }
        }
        return "No Parameters Found";
    }

}
```

It was working okay when I had a `URL` like this

`https://example.com/?&page=2`

But now, my `URL` is like this:

`https://example.com/?&page=2&order=my_id&direction=ASC`.

My `function` still replaces `page=2` as `page=3` etc, but other values are **appended** to my whole `URL`. How can I replace all these `params` in my `URL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) and [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115)

Comment: Check the duplicates. Use [**URL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [**URLSearchParams**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead of manually splitting and looping. Like this: `new URL( window.document.URL).searchParams.get(paramName)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split by both `?` and `&` to get all of the params then you process them by your logic after that.

```js
const url = "https://example.com/?&page=2&order=my_id&direction=ASC"
console.log(url.split(/[\?\&]/))
```